# Element DOM modifications in custom Vue directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, directive

I am using a custom directive which hides or shows a component. A custom directive is used because the component's visibility is based on logic which is difficult to squeeze into a `v-show` condition (and there are actually many components, so it's easier to use this custom directive).

The problem is that since the custom directive directly sets the element's `style.visibility` and `style.display`, it somewhat clashes with Vue's own `v-show` (at least that's my explanation for why this sometimes fails). My theory is that the element is re-rendered at part of the virtual DOM rendering and thus direct style modifications in element are overridden.

Since `beforeMount` allows access to the `vnode` (`beforeMount(element, binding, vnode)`), it should be possible to directly modify the vnode, so any existing logic on `v-show` could be merged with the custom directive's logic (merged into `v-show`). Is that possible or advised? The Vue documentation is a little scant in that area.

Has anyone tried this before or has any ideas that could help?

Comment: *Is that possible or advised? The Vue documentation is a little scant in that area.* - this is a legit technique to customize the behaviour of third-party comps by modifying vnodes, both in Vue and React. Whether this is advisable is up to you. Since you rely on internals of a thing you don't own, this may be changed without a notice and require to fork a lib any way.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @orange Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem? Perhaps the issue is caused by your directive implementation.

Comment: Contrary to what I thought, I now think it's perfectly fine to set styles directly in the directive (found this example: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/custom-directives.html#_3-x-syntax). In my case I had a directive which does similar things to `v-show` (hide/show component, but based on a value and some other logic instead of just a plain condition as in `v-show`). Both, my custom directive and v-show (if also specified), clash. `v-show` may want to show the component, my custom directive wasn't to hide it. I settled for `v-if` instead of `v-show` (=equiv. to ANDing both directives).